# Opening a .css file crashes Visual Studio?

Tags: css, visual-studio, visual-studio-2012

When I open any .css file in any project in Visual Studio 2012, it immediately crashes.

I've tried restarting my computer, reinstalling Visual Studio, installing a Visual Studio update and uninstalling all of my Visual Studio extensions.

The problem started this morning - last night I had a power outage and my computer, which was running Visual Studio at the time, crashed.

I wish I could supply more details but this is all I have. The problem isn't specific to a project or a file, but (AFAIK) only to .css files.

Edit: Running Visual Studio in Safe Mode fixes the problem in some projects but not in all - specifically, in a standalone, standard website project I can edit .css files fine, but in my TFS-hosted team project I can't, which is making it impossible for me to work.. When exiting safe mode, .css files in general crash Visual Studio.

To clarify: The problem isn't that Visual Studio gives me some sort of error message when I try to load a .css file, Visual Studio just *crashes*. I've tried reinstalling, restarting, and repairing, nothing works. There have been similiar complaints that I've found but they all have something to do with some extension messing Visual Studio up.. The only extensions I had were Web Essentials and Resharper, both now uninstalled, and they worked fine until this morning.

Comment: Can you provide stack trace? To collect stack trace, check event viewer by calling eventvwr from run window. Check for event with VS crash. Else attach Debugger to crashing VS instance. Open 2 instances of VS. In one instance open your project without opening css file. Attach debugger to devenv.exe process from other instance of VS. Set catch all .Net exceptions by opening exceptions dialog(ctrl+Alt+E). Then open CSS file which is causing the crash. I guess VS might be trying to load some extension dlls and crashing on your machine.

Comment: If you didn't already find this, it may help... http://connect.microsoft.com/VisualStudio/feedback/details/530414/css-file-crash

Comment: rename your css file, with .txt extension and try !

Comment: I would suggest an uninstall , reinstall. I had a buggy extension that was breaking vs and that was the only solution that worked

Answer (score -1):

i think it's better to try Visual Studio reset. Do you tired using any other software like Dreamweaver?